# Why is radial probability density exactly zero at the center?

Tags: physical-chemistry, atomic-structure

I have read that the radial probability density is exactly zero at $r = 0$ because the radial probability density is

$$P(r) = \psi^2\,\mathrm dv,\tag{1}$$

where $\mathrm dv$ is the volume of spherical shell of infinitesimal width, i.e. the volume between sphere of $r + \mathrm dr$ and $\mathrm dr$ radius, and

$$\mathrm dv = 4\pi r^2\,\mathrm dr,\label{q-eqn-02}\tag{2}$$

and thus when $r = 0,$ $\mathrm dv = 0$ and the radial probability density is exactly zero. But \eqref{q-eqn-02} is an approximation as the the actual volume of spherical shell of an infinitesimally small width is equal to

\begin{align}
\mathrm dv &= \frac 4 3\pi (r + \mathrm dr)^3 - \frac 4 3\pi r^3 \\
  &= \frac 4 3\pi (r^3 + 3r^2\,\mathrm dr + 3r\,\mathrm dr^2 + \mathrm dr^3 − r^3) \\
  &= \frac 4 3\pi (3r^2\,\mathrm dr + 3r\,\mathrm dr^2 + \mathrm dr^3).\tag{3}
\end{align}

Thus when $r = 0,$ $\mathrm dv = 4/3\pi\,\mathrm dr^3$ instead of $\mathrm dv = 0,$ and $\mathrm dr^3$ approaches zero, but it is not exactly zero. The radial probability density at $r = 0$ should be approximately equal to zero instead of exactly zero as stated in the books. What am I missing?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138197/discussion-on-question-by-hsdfasdafhakdfhasiog-why-is-radial-probability-density).

Answer (score 2):

Poutnik's comment is right on the money.  I'll try to put this in intuitive terms.  In calculus we routinely add up an infinite number of zeroes to get a finite sum, so it may seem like you can work with squares or cubes of dr and still get something other than zero.  Of course in a sense you *can* ... if you're doing multiple integration and are focused only on the *rate* a rate increases.  But here we are simply integrating over the first dr.  We allow that one zero into our math, but if you multiply by dr again, the effect really *is* zero.

Another way to think of it: we're adding up the entire volume of the sphere, by looking at the sum for an infinite number of radius values.  While the volume for the area at any given radius, plainly evaluated, is zero, they represent *shells* of an infinite number of points.  Each one covers an *area* in the shape of the surface of a sphere.  But at r=0, there is no area - there's just that one single point.  For any other r, you would have to cut up the spherical shell two different ways into an infinite number of tiny bits to get pieces that small.  And if you did that, you'd reduce the rate by which the volume of the sphere goes up ... to zero.

Okay, one *more* way, because this does confuse students and it can be hard to explain it sensibly.  Suppose I want to start adding up the volume, just the volume, of a sphere or spherically symmetrical distribution.  Now suppose I give a kid a crayon and ask him to color in a picture of an s orbital, and he diligently scrawls around with the crayon, while a sophisticated AI turns that into an inferred 3D wiggly line.  Taking the time at which any point was drawn as a parameter t, the computer even extrapolates after the tyke grew tired, and before he began, so that there is an (x,y,z) point specified for every real-number time t from negative infinity to infinity.  Now whatever that curve is, whether it passes through (0,0,0) or not, whether it repeats itself or not, the calculation of the volume starts the same way - by unfolding it into a simple line along one dimension t.  And it ends the same way, by noting any geometric line has volume zero.  Now here you're interested in a probability density, but the point is: the density is never infinite, and so it can multiply by the volume of the line to get only one thing: zero.  No matter what the scribble, even though it was done for an infinite time, the particle is still *certainly* somewhere else when you look!  That's what having three real-number coordinates to play with will do for you.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathrm{d}P=|\Psi|^2\mathrm{d}V$

$r=0 \implies x=y=z=0 \implies \mathrm{d}V=0,$

giving just a point with zero volume.

Therefore $\mathrm{d}P=0$ as  well, as $|\Psi|^2$ is finite.

We can also express it as

$\mathrm{d}P=|\Psi|^24\pi r^2\mathrm{d}r$

which is for r=0 exactly zero, however dr is or is not zero.